# Regex match being overwritten

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to sanitise a phone number using Regex.

I don't want any separating characters between digits and I don't want the local (0) part. Separators could be any non-digit character.

ie. the number could be:

- +44 (00) 845 740 4404
- +44-(00)-845-740-4404
- +44-(00)-845-740=4404 (unlikely but could be a typo)

This matches the (0) part fine:

http://regex101.com/r/cB6hN4/3

But if I add |\D+ to match a non-digit character, it overwrites my first match:

http://regex101.com/r/cB6hN4/2

How do I keep both matches within in the one regex?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
\((\d+)\)|(?:(?!\(\d+\))\D)+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cB6hN4/7)

`(?:(?!\(\d+\))\D)+` matches one or more non-digit characters but not of `(\d+)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To further clarify for future readers, from what I understand there is no way to simply say 'keep previous matches': you just have to be more clever with your matching.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `|\D+` at the end try to use `|[^()\d]+`

The regex will be `\((\d+)\)|[^()\d]+`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cB6hN4/8)

But take into account that the parenthesis could not be used as a separator as you can see in the demo

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is the most understandable, though the second one catches brackets as separators. http://regex101.com/r/cB6hN4/9